# Showing something is a principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove the following:
Let $K$ be a number field and let $\theta\in \mathcal{O}_K$ satisfy $Nm(\theta)=6$. Prove that $\langle 2,\theta\rangle\langle 3,\theta\rangle=\langle\theta\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $a, b \in \Bbb Z$ are coprime, we can write $am+bn=1$ for some $m, n \in \Bbb Z$ by [Bézout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), so:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
(a, \theta) (b, \theta)
&=& (ab, a\theta, b\theta, \theta^2) \\
&=& (ab, a\theta, b\theta, \theta^2, (am+bn)\theta) \\
&=& (ab, a\theta, b\theta, \theta^2, \theta) \\
&=& (\theta)
\end{array}$$

since $\theta$ divides everything else on the list ($N_{K/\Bbb Q}(\theta) = \prod_{\sigma \in \operatorname{Hom}(K,\Bbb C)} \sigma(\theta)$).